# Can I use parameters in a CREATE query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, create-table

Actually I have 2 questions, both in SQL Server.

1. There's a query like "Create Table" but for Create columns? If it exist, please, how it is?
2. I need to use a "Create Table" but using parameters, but I don't know if that is possible.
   For example:

   > ```
   > @table_name string,
   > @column_name1 int,
   > @column_name2 int,
   > @column_name3 int
   >
   > CREATE TABLE @table_name
   >     (
   >     @column_name1,
   >     @column_name2,
   >     @column_name3
   >     ....
   >     );
   > ```

Obviously that's only what I have in mind and doesn't work. There is a right way to do it?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: You can try altering the table by adding a new column ALTER TABLE _tablename ADD newColumn varchar(10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, use ALTER TABLE command.

For #2, how are you executing the query? You can create a string variable first with the complete command and table name as parameter and then execute the query. Something like:

```
declare @ CustomerID int 

set @ CustomerID = 3262833

declare @sql nvarchar(1000)



set @sql = N'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [tbCustomers] WITH (NOLOCK) 

WHERE  tbCustomers.ID = '+ + cast(@CustomerID as nvarchar(10))   



exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. By creating a column probably you mean adding a column to an existing table, right?

   use **ALTER TABLE** for that

   ALTER TABLE TableName ADD newColumn datatype

More info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

2. For dynamically creating a table, try using **sp_executesql** function

   ```
     sp_executesql 'CREATE TABLE @table_name @column_name1 datatype1, 
        @column_name2 datatype2, 
        @column_name3 datatype3 
     )', 
     N'@table_name varchar(100),  
       @column_name1 varchar(100), 
       @column_name2 varchar(100),  
       @column_name3 varchar(100)', 
       @table_name, 
       @column_name1, 
       @column_name2, 
       @column_name3
   ```

More info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE create_table 
    @table varchar(10),
    @ID varchar(10),
    @Name varchar(20)

AS
BEGIN
    Declare @sql nvarchar(MAX)
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    Set @sql = 'CREATE TABLE '+@table+'('+@ID+' bigint NOT NULL,'+@Name+' varchar(25)) ON [PRIMARY]';
    exec (@sql)
END
GO
```